# How to compile for armv7s devices

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, gstreamer, iphone-5

My project support only armv7.
How do i compile project for armv7s devices?

Comment: You need to start ensuring you have 64-bit support. It is only a matter of time before Apple makes this compulsory. Either change library or assist the maintainers in making it 64-bit compatible.

Comment: See https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=732806 for my answer to the same question some time ago.

Comment: Yeah, that's what we use to build the binaries for Android, iOS, OS X and Windows. The reason for not including the armv7s and other variants is explained in that bug report though.

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to provide the actual information here and not just a link. [Link-only answers are not considered good answers and will probably be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just try to remove `armv7s`  architecture from your project supported arch. in settings. Work as for me, app still running on iphone 5 and so on!

Comment: temporarily it would be a good advice, but in long term that is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Attempt to build from source which is available at [the gstreamer project](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org)

The maintainers may be able to provide you with the process and or makefiles.

Once you figure it out you can provide the results to the project. Give back a little.